# Is there a connection between sonarqube eclipse plugin and maven plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, maven-plugin

Is sonarqube eclipse plugin executing a `sonar:sonar` maven goal in the background?
If so, can we change which maven plugin version eclipse plugin uses?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version. In latest versions, the SonarQube Eclipse plugin uses the SonarQube Runner API, so Maven is not involved.

Comment: didn't know that, thanks. does that mean that there is a sonarqube eclipse plugin that run agains maven task?